# Is it expected for UIView to show up on window even with no VC controller on window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to understand if `UIView` can show on window even when **no** `ViewController` has been pushed onto the `window`.

Is that correct behavior?

- I was trying to show an alert of "Internet Offline" from **AppDelegate** based on **notifications**.
- I chose `AppDelegate` to be **independent** of any VC currently on the stack
- But I found I can show `Alerts` even if there is no `RootViewController` on the **window**

is this expected?

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
// I am able to show alert here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view controller simply shows its view in the window. So there is no reason why you can't simply show a view in the window without a view controller. There's nothing special about the view controller when it comes to showing a view.